# Apply pandas function on column only on certain rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
|   user  |       category    | val  | 
| ------  | ------------------| -----|
| user 1  | c1                |   3  |  
| user 1  | c2                |   4  |
| user 1  | c3                |   8  | 
| user 2  | c1                |   5  |
| user 2  | c2                |   9  | 
| user 2  | c3                |   10 |
```

Let's say I want to apply a function f onto the val column. What's the best way to return a dataframe so f is only applied to values where the category is c1, for example?

```
|   user  |       category    | val     |
| ------  | ------------------| -----   | 
| user 1  | c1                |   f(3)  | 
| user 1  | c2                |   4     | 
| user 1  | c3                |   8     | 
| user 2  | c1                |  f(5)   | 
| user 2  | c2                |   9     |
| user 2  | c3                |   10    |
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['val'] = np.where(df['category'] == 'c1', df['val'].apply(f), df['val'])
```

Or filter with `loc`:

```
mask = df['category'] == 'c1'
df.loc[mask, 'val'] = df.loc[mask, 'val'].apply(f)
```

Comment: Thank you! one thing, could you explain how np.where works? I'm having trouble understanding what the three arguments are for, and what each one does (specifically the second and third).

Comment: @hedebyhedge - Sure, it create numpy array by condition - if condition is True, add value from `df['val'].apply(f)` and if `False` add value from `df['val']` to output.